# running postgresql image with podman failed

Tags: archlinux, postgresql-11, podman

When running postgresql alpine image with podman :

> podman run --name postgres -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test -e POSTGRES_USER=test -d postgres:11-alpine

the result is :

> Error: /usr/bin/slirp4netns failed: "open(\"/dev/net/tun\"): No such device\nWARNING: Support for sandboxing is experimental\nchild failed(1)\nWARNING: Support for sandboxing is experimental\n"

The running system is archlinux. Is there a way to fix this error or a turn arround ?

Thanks

Comment: What are the versions of `podman` and `slirp4netns`? I recall there was a similar bug with device nodes for unprivileged containers, and it was fixed some time ago...

Answer (score 1):

1. Is slirp4netns correctly installed? Check the project [Site](https://github.com/rootless-containers/slirp4netns) for information.
2. Sometimes the flag order matters. try `-d` first and `-p` last (directly infornt of the image) looking like:

   - `podman run -d --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test -e POSTGRES_USER=test -p 5432:5432 postgres:11-alpine`
3. Try only creating the neccessary password, then log into your container and create manually (this always worked for me)

   1. `podman run -d --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test -p 5432:5432 postgres:11-alpline`

      1. `podman exec -it postgres bash`
      2. Create default user postgres

         - `su - postgres`
      3. start postgres

         - `psql`
      4. create databases and tables

         - `CREATE USER testuser WITH PASSWORD 'testpassword'` |  [Doku](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/sql-createuser.html)
         - `CREATE DATABASE testdata WITH OWNER testuser`
      5. Check if it worked

         - `\l+`
   2. Connect to your Database via IP and Port

Answer (score 1):

I assume you upgraded Arch packages recently. Most likely your system needs a restart.

Comment: After podman 2.2.1 update and system reboot, the problem was fixed. Thx to all.

Comment: @Ruddy32 if restart solved your problem, how about accepting the answer?